# Pop the highest value from a priority queue while removing some related nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, stl, graph-algorithm, priority-queue

Suppose we have a priority queue of `n` nodes of a graph. Each node is assigned a key, and all nodes are sorted in the priority queue based on the key value.

With the [right implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation), popping the head key (the node with the highest key value) from this queue takes `O(log(n))` time.

But what if it is also required to remove all fanout and fanins of the head node from the priority queue? The obvious implementation would be to search all nodes in the queue and if they were on fanin or fanout of the head, remove them. This will make the run time for POP to be  `O(nlog(n))`.

Can we do any better? Is there any better data structure that can provide a better runtime?

Comment: it would probably be more efficient to maintain array of nodes sorted by key. whenever we need to remove a node, we linearly remove all fanouts-fanins in a single traversal, given that you keep fanouts-fanins info in a separate data structure

Comment: @mangusta: This will take O(n), right? I was hoping we can get something closer to the original O(log(n)) for popping from a priority queue. Also, I still need the push operation of the priority queue, which is less efficient in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is a priority queue with an additional *delete* operation. In order to make it in an efficient way (that is if you want to remove k nodes from the queue, it would take O(k*log n)), you need a handle on the nodes.

A usual way to do that is to have an array which associates a vertex's id to the node in the priority queue. Then, the deletion algorithm depends of which priority queue is implemented.

I don't think you can do any better in terms of performance, because the other solution consisting in maintaining a sorted array is more expensive (have to maintain the array sorted for each modification).

Comment: you don't have to sort a sorted array for every modification. when you insert a new node, you find its proper position by binary search. (although it is still linear versus logn in case of pr.queue)

Comment: True, I went a bit fast on this, thanks your correcting me

Comment: tradeoff anyhow. keeping nodes in pr.queue would have worse performance in dense graphs since k is going to be very close to n

Comment: @T.Claverie: you mention `"A usual way to do that is to have an array which associates a vertex's id to the node in the priority queue"`. I assume you mean as we POP a node, we use this array to find the head node and its fanin/fanouts in the queue and remove them. But finding the head node itself and its fanin/fanout in the array takes `O(n)` time unless a better data structure is used?

Comment: No, we pop the node from the priority queue, which is O(log n). Then you get the id of the node and use it to retrieve its adjacent nodes in the graph. You can find examples of such priority queues here: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/
(examples are IndexMinPQ, IndexMultiwayMinPQ, IndexBinomialMinPQ and IndexFibonacciMinPQ)

Answer (score 0):

As you build your priority queue, build a hash table that has, for every node, its position in the array that is used to host the priority queue. Now when you modify the priority queue, you typically do this by swapping two elements in the array. Every time you do this you update the values in the hash table, so that it still holds the correct offset in the priority queue array for each node. This is just a constant time overhead on the operations that implement the priority queue.

Now what you need to do is to write code to take an arbitrary node, read its offset in the priority queue from the hash table, remove the element at that offset from the priority queue array, and then remove the node and its associated value from the hash table.

The only tricky thing is to remove an element from an arbitrary position in the priority queue array (which I take to be a heap) and restore the invariants of the heap. Each element will have at most one parent and at most two children. Assuming the highest priority is at the top each element must be no higher than its parent and at least as high as either of its children. If you now swap the element with largest valid array index with the element you are removing its key may either increase or decrease, so you may break one of these two invariants, but not both.

If the element is now larger than its parent, you use the standard heap invariant fix-up that moves towards the top of the heap. This can only increase the keys in the elements it displaces, so when it finishes the heap invariants are restored. If the element is now smaller than one of its children (more likely) you swap it with the larger of those two children and carry on down as usual.

In either case this amounts to a standard heap sift up or sift down (with the extra book-keeping to keep the hash table up to date) so the cost is O(log n)).

(Alternatively, don't use a priority queue at all, but a datastructure like a java TreeMap or TreeSet, which is an associative array with an operation that allows you to retrieve the element in the array with the largest (or smallest) key in which case you have very little to implement, and each operation is still O(log n).